# How do I use the oauth gem to validate a token passed into the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I am trying to build a service that authenticates users using an oauth 1 signed request. The request includes an oauth token, signature, nonce, and consumer key. The server has access to the corresponding secrets, but it is unclear how to use the oauth gem to validate the token and retrieve the corresponding user. The token was originally generated using the oauth-rails plugin, but the validation needs to take place on a different server from the original rails application (but has access to the same underlying database).

How can I use the oauth gem to accomplish this?

I have looked through the source for the oauth and oauth-plugin gems, but I can't tell where this validation actually happens. Almost all of the documentation I can find refers to using the oauth gem as a consumer, not a provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer to this, so I'll put it here in the hopes of helping someone in the future.

Once you've retrieved the AccessToken and ClientApplication objects from the underlying database and checked the nonce and timestamp, verifying the signature is as easy as:

signature = OAuth::Signature.verify(request, {}) do |sigblock|
  [token.secret, ca.secret]
end

If the signature checks out, signature will be true. Beware - if you're behind an http proxy such as nginx, the SERVER_PORT environment variable may not be correctly set for https requests and you may have to set it manually. If this (or any other seemingly tiny part of the request) is off, it can cause the signature verification to fail even if the request is valid.